# How to fit the div height to the span height

Tags: html, css

```css
.headerDesc {
    width: 100% + 1px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #4d2765;
    margin: 0 -8px;    
}
.headerDesc span {
    padding: 5px;  
    position: absolute;    
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;    
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerDesc">
    <span><strong>A ciência do raciocínio lógico e abstrato, que estuda quantidades, medidas, espaços, estruturas, variações e estatísticas</strong></span>
</div>
```

I'd like to know how to fit the div height to the span's

I set the div height to 70px because on my phone the span is wraped in 3 lines, but on other phones the lines can be wraped in 2 lines, so the div is going to be bigger than the span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the height and width from your div and also take out the absolute positioning from the span you get the result you want.

```
.headerDesc {
    background-color: #4d2765;
    margin: 0 -8px;    
}
.headerDesc span {
    padding: 5px;  
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

If you want to change the styling on other devices you should use [media queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/). Generally it is a bad idea to use the `height` property.

Comment: Get it. Actually, this site will be implemented in an android application. I'm trying to make it reponsive.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this
I just added the background color to `.headerDesc > span` from `.headerDesc`

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}
.headerDesc span {
    padding: 5px;  
    position: absolute;    
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;    
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background-color: #4d2765;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerDesc">
    <span><strong>A ciência do raciocínio lógic saveo e abstrato, que estuda quantidades, medidas, espaços, estruturas, variações e estatísticas</strong></span>
</div>
```

Comment: What's this jsfiddle? nothing changed but this

Answer (score 0):

Using display property inline-block and setting height to inherit the height of span will be same as that of div element.

```
    .headerDesc {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #4d2765;
    margin: 0 -8px;    
}
.headerDesc span {
    display : inline-block;
    heigh : inherit;
    padding: 5px;  
    position: absolute;    
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;    
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

Comment: It didn't worked. I want the div's height to be changed to the span's height. Get it? Jacques' idea worked for me.